# How to run wire along 2x3 studs

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement

Doing a basement build, using 2x3 studs for drywalling over wrapped insulation. How do I fasten the nmsc to the studs? I’m not about to drill through these smaller studs because the wood is already thinner than 2x4.
Any wrap-around type staple or other solutions available?

Answer (score 6):

2x3 studs are only (correctly) used for non-load-bearing walls, (as far as I understand) and **certainly the wall in question is not load bearing.**

[Non-bearing studs can be notched 40% or drilled 60% per code.](https://www.iccsafe.org/wp-content/uploads/IRC-6-1.pdf) That's a 1 inch notch or a 1-1/2" hole on a 2-1/2" "2x3" in the "3" direction.

Drilling holes for NM cable is utterly not a problem. Use protective plates if your wires end up within 1-1/2" of the room-facing edge of the stud, and keep your holes at least 5/8" from either edge.

Comment: * 1-1/4" of the room facing edge of stud.